# How to restore files deleted with "git rm *"?

Tags: git

Accidentally i  deleted all files after 1st commit on local repo using `git rm *` .

Git commit

```
git commit -m 'IF ELSE'
[master fc9895a] IF ELSE
 14 files changed, 3234 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 Lecture 03 - Bootstrapping.ppt
 create mode 100644 Makefile
 create mode 100644 codegenerator.cpp
 create mode 100644 error.cpp
 create mode 100644 error.h
 create mode 100644 includelex.h
 create mode 100644 includeyacc.h
 create mode 100644 lexrule.l
 create mode 100644 rule.tab.c
 create mode 100644 stable.h
 create mode 100644 symboletable.cpp
 create mode 100644 test.c
 create mode 100644 yaccrule.y
 create mode 100644 yaccrule2.y

git rm *
rm 'Lecture 03 - Bootstrapping.ppt'
rm 'Makefile'
rm 'README.md'
rm 'codegenerator.cpp'
rm 'error.cpp'
rm 'error.h'
rm 'includelex.h'
rm 'includeyacc.h'
rm 'lexrule.l'
rm 'rule.tab.c'
rm 'stable.h'
rm 'symboletable.cpp'
rm 'test.c'
rm 'yaccrule.y'
```

Sequence of commands that i used to restore .

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    Lecture 03 - Bootstrapping.ppt
    deleted:    Makefile
    deleted:    README.md
    deleted:    codegenerator.cpp
    deleted:    error.cpp
    deleted:    error.h
    deleted:    includelex.h
    deleted:    includeyacc.h
    deleted:    lexrule.l
    deleted:    rule.tab.c
    deleted:    stable.h
    deleted:    symboletable.cpp
    deleted:    test.c
    deleted:    yaccrule.y
    deleted:    yaccrule2.y

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .hg/
```

```
git reset --hard HEAD^1
HEAD is now at 9b72b0c first commit
```

```
git reset --hard HEAD
HEAD is now at 9b72b0c first commit
```

```
 git checkout
 Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

```
 git reset HEAD test.c
 git reset HEAD  Makefile
 git reset HEAD --  Makefile

git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .hg/
```

I am unable to restore file on Ubuntu 14.10 ,git version 2.1.0 .
Is there a way so that i can restore file?

Comment: As I understand it, you had two commits: `9b72b0c` (`first commit`), and `fc9895a` (`IF ELSE`). Correct?

Comment: No first commit is generated by reset command .

Comment: That doesn't make sense; the `reset` command doesn't create commits. What do you mean by that? Anyway, based on your description of the problem, `git reset --hard fc9895a` would fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solves the problem .Can you explain bit how did it works.

Comment: See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: The message that i wrote was exactly copied from terminal . I am sure that `first commit`  message was generated by `reset` command.

Comment: No. As I wrote, `git reset` does not create commits. What happened is that `git reset --hard HEAD^1` simply reset your `master` branch to the parent of the `fc9895a` commit; the parent in question (`9b72b0c`) already existed before you ran that `git reset` command. See my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Detective work

Based on your description of the problem, before running into trouble, your repo's history must have consisted of two commits:

```
9b72b0c first commit
fc9895a IF ELSE (HEAD, master)
```

#### Evidence

- Information about your second commit is in the output of

  ```
  git commit -m 'IF ELSE'
  ```
- The output of

  ```
  git reset --hard HEAD^1
  ```

  (this commands resets the current branch to the *parent* of the current commit) indicates that the parent of `fc9895a` has SHA `9b72b0c` and message `first commit`.

### Reset your branch to the desired state

Since you haven't made any local changes after running `git rm *`, all you have to do is go back to the state your repository was in right after you made the `IF ELSE` commit.

Fortunately, you still have a record of the short SHA of that commit: `fc9895a`. Therefore,

```
git reset --hard fc9895a
```

is the command that will get you out of trouble.

#### Explanation

`git-reset` is used to reset the current branch (`master`, here) to the specified state (`fc9895a`, here).

And the [`git-reset` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) describes the `--hard` flag thus:

> `--hard`
>
> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files   in the working tree since `<commit>` are discarded.

(Use with caution!)

[Here](http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html) is a good introduction to how `git-reset` works.

Comment: git-reset --hard seems not only to restore the deleted files, but also to discard any changes made to to working tree. What if I have accidentally deleted one file using git-rm which I want to restore, but I want to keep the changes to the other files in in the working tree?